# Boa noite fiz um codigo de votação/pesquisa, mas ele não tá computando o voto quando é dito pelo nome ao invés do número

Tags: python, python-3.x, idle-ide

Fiz uma linha de código pra fazer uma pesquisa numa rua pra saber qual canal as pessoas assistem, e eu coloquei pra computar o voto pelo número do canal ou pelo nome do canal, mas ele só computa os votos feitos pelo número e não pelo nome, podem me dar uma luz ?

```
def pesquisa_audiencia (canal):
    global canal_cultura, canal_globo, canal_band, canal_record

    if canal.isalpha():
        if canal== 'Encerrar':
            print('Encerrado')
            print_resultados()

    elif canal.isalnum():
        if canal == '2' or canal == 'Cultura' or canal == '4' or canal == 'Globo' or canal == '7' or canal == 'Band' or canal == '9' or canal == 'Record':
            if canal == '2':
                canal_cultura +=1
            elif canal == 'Cultura':
                canal_cultura +=1
            elif canal == '4':
                canal_globo +=1
            elif canal == 'Globo':
                canal_globo +=1
            elif canal == '7':
                canal_band +=1
            elif canal == 'Band':
                canal_band +=1
            elif canal == '9':
                canal_record +=1
            elif canal == 'Record':
                canal_record +=1
     
        

def print_resultados():
    global canal_cultura, canal_globo, canal_band, canal_record

    print('Porcentagem de Audiência por canal:\n')
    print('Canal 2:' + str(canal_cultura))
    print('Canal 4:' + str(canal_globo))
    print('Canal 7:' + str(canal_band))
    print('Canal 9:' + str(canal_record))


    exit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    canal_cultura = 0
    canal_globo = 0
    canal_band = 0
    canal_record = 0

    while True:
        canal = input('Qual canal estão assistindo neste momento em sua casa?')
        pesquisa_audiencia(canal)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qual versão do python voce está usando? Dê uma olhada nesse link: [A diferença das funções input() e raw_input()](https://www.alura.com.br/artigos/a-diferenca-das-funcoes-input-e-raw-input-no-python?gclid=Cj0KCQjw1a6EBhC0ARIsAOiTkrHGClSBfY11TU3aMtavbDByJ0t_Z75FIKTf7fQo-0CONTPlW6kjn6MaAikREALw_wcB)

Se estiver usando Python 2, use ***raw_input*** ao inves de ***input***.

```
def pesquisa_audiencia (canal):
    global canal_cultura, canal_globo, canal_band, canal_record

    if canal == "Encerrar":
        print('Encerrado')
        print_resultados()

    if canal == '2' or canal == 'Cultura':
        canal_cultura +=1
    elif canal == '4' or canal == 'Globo':
        canal_globo +=1
    elif canal == '7' or canal == 'Band':
        canal_band +=1
    elif canal == '9' or canal == 'Record':
        canal_record +=1     
    else:
        print("Voto nao computado")

def print_resultados():
    global canal_cultura, canal_globo, canal_band, canal_record

    print('Porcentagem de Audiencia por canal:')
    print('Canal 2 - ' + str(canal_cultura)) + " votos"
    print('Canal 4 - ' + str(canal_globo)) + " votos"
    print('Canal 7 - ' + str(canal_band)) + " votos"
    print('Canal 9 - ' + str(canal_record)) + " votos"
    exit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    canal_cultura = 0
    canal_globo = 0
    canal_band = 0
    canal_record = 0

    while True:
        canal = raw_input('Qual canal estao assistindo neste momento em sua casa?')
        pesquisa_audiencia(canal)
```

Se estiver usando Python 3, nos dê mais informacoes sobre os erros.